# Want to make the text rotated and transparent at once in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm new in newer FPDF version to make change from old version to new version for repairing the PDF system in the newer server. When I've tried to make the text rotated and transparent, It errors that shows "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: No page has been added yet in /var/www/html/pdf/fpdf/fpdf.php:271".

I tried to use a reference from http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script2.php and http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script74.php to make this.

So, i put this 3 classes in 1 file:

```
use setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection;

require_once('../../pdf/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('../../pdf/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
require_once('../../pdf/fpdi-protection/src/autoload.php');

//require('../../pdf/fpdf/rotation.php');
require('../../pdf/fpdf/fpdf_merge.php');

//Transparent
class AlphaPDF extends FPDF
{
    protected $extgstates = array();

    function SetAlpha($alpha, $bm='Normal')
    {
        $gs = $this->AddExtGState(array('ca'=>$alpha, 'CA'=>$alpha, 'BM'=>'/'.$bm));
        $this->SetExtGState($gs);
    }

    function AddExtGState($parms)
    {
        $n = count($this->extgstates)+1;
        $this->extgstates[$n]['parms'] = $parms;
        return $n;
    }

    function SetExtGState($gs)
    {
        $this->_out(sprintf('/GS%d gs', $gs));
    }

    function _enddoc()
    {
        if(!empty($this->extgstates) && $this->PDFVersion<'1.4')
            $this->PDFVersion='1.4';
        parent::_enddoc();
    }

    function _putextgstates()
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($this->extgstates); $i++)
        {
            $this->_newobj();
            $this->extgstates[$i]['n'] = $this->n;
            $this->_put('<</Type /ExtGState');
            $parms = $this->extgstates[$i]['parms'];
            $this->_put(sprintf('/ca %.3F', $parms['ca']));
            $this->_put(sprintf('/CA %.3F', $parms['CA']));
            $this->_put('/BM '.$parms['BM']);
            $this->_put('>>');
            $this->_put('endobj');
        }
    }

    function _putresourcedict()
    {
        parent::_putresourcedict();
        $this->_put('/ExtGState <<');
        foreach($this->extgstates as $k=>$extgstate)
            $this->_put('/GS'.$k.' '.$extgstate['n'].' 0 R');
        $this->_put('>>');
    }

    function _putresources()
    {
        $this->_putextgstates();
        parent::_putresources();
    }
}

//Rotated
class PDF_Rotate extends FPDF
{
var $angle=0;

    function Rotate($angle,$x=-1,$y=-1)
    {
        if($x==-1)
            $x=$this->x;
        if($y==-1)
            $y=$this->y;
        if($this->angle!=0)
            $this->_out('Q');
        $this->angle=$angle;
        if($angle!=0)
        {
            $angle*=M_PI/180;
            $c=cos($angle);
            $s=sin($angle);
            $cx=$x*$this->k;
            $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k;
            $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5F %.5F %.5F %.5F %.2F %.2F cm 1 0 0 1 %.2F %.2F cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy));
        }
    }
    
    function _endpage()
    {
        if($this->angle!=0)
        {
            $this->angle=0;
            $this->_out('Q');
        }
        parent::_endpage();
    }
}

//Rotating Object
class PDF extends PDF_Rotate
{
    
    function RotatedText($x,$y,$txt,$angle)
    {
         $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
         $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
         $this->Rotate(0);
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF();
```

and it begins in $pdf = new PDF();

And this is the error part (in the same file which I put 3 classes) :

```
if ($height>=$width)
    {$pdf->AddPage('P','A4');
     $pdf->Image($imagefilePath,2,4,208,293);
         $pdf = new AlphaPDF();
         $pdf->SetAlpha(0.5);
          
         $pdf = new PDF();
         $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '',15);
         $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
          
         $pdf->RotatedText(105-90, 148.5-120,'CONTROLLED COPY',45);
         $pdf->RotatedText(105-90, 148.5+7-120,$nmrdvl,45);
          
         $pdf->RotatedText(105-25, 148.5,'CONTROLLED COPY',45);
         $pdf->RotatedText(105-25, 148.5+7,$nmrdvl,45);
          
         $pdf->RotatedText(105+35, 148.5+120,'CONTROLLED COPY',45);
         $pdf->RotatedText(105+35, 148.5+7+120,$nmrdvl,45);
          
         //$pdf->MultiCell(105,148.5,'CONTROLLED COPY'."\n ".$nmrdvl,0,'C','');
         $pdf = new AlphaPDF();
         $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
          
         $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
         $pdf = new PDF();
          
     } else
    {$pdf->AddPage('L','A4');
     $pdf->Image($imagefilePath,2,4,293,208);
         $pdf = new AlphaPDF();
         $pdf->SetAlpha(0.5);
          
         $pdf = new PDF();
         $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '',15);
         $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
          
         $pdf->RotatedText(148.5-120, 105-85, 'CONTROLLED COPY',45);
         $pdf->RotatedText(148.5-120, 105+7-85, $nmrdvl,45);
          
         $pdf->RotatedText(148.5-25, 105, 'CONTROLLED COPY',45);
         $pdf->RotatedText(148.5-25, 105+7, $nmrdvl,45);
          
         $pdf->RotatedText(148.5+70, 105+85, 'CONTROLLED COPY',45);
         $pdf->RotatedText(148.5+70, 105+7+85, $nmrdvl,45);
          
         //$pdf->MultiCell(148.5,105,'CONTROLLED COPY'."\n ".$nmrdvl,0,'C','');
         $pdf = new AlphaPDF();
         $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
          
         $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
         $pdf = new PDF();
     }
```

So, how should I do to solve this error and how do to make the text rotated and transparent at once using FPDF to make PDF file from PHP?

P.S : PHP version is 8.1.2 and FPDF version is 1.84

Comment: Check out [FAQ #13](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q13).